# jQuery Accordion Issues Here

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create jQuery accordion that slides down and up when the icon (font awesome) with a class "fa fa-angle-double-right" was click. Then it will change to another icon class "fa fa-angle-double-down" (which is a down arrow) when the accordion shows the content.

```
) {
            $(this)
                .next()
```

If you could help me show me the JSFIDDLE solution that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with just using CSS and the same icon and it looks kind of cool too:

http://jsfiddle.net/3fpaa648/6/

Add CSS:

```
dt i {
  transition: all .5s;
}
dt.active i {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

You can use a different class method but I used it for simplicity:

```
(function() {
    $('dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').addClass('hide');
    $('dl').on('click', 'dt', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('dt').removeClass('active');
        $(this)
            .next()
                .slideDown(300)
                .siblings('dd')
                    .slideUp(300);
    });
})();
```

However to answer your original question using the method you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/3fpaa648/7/

Add this to your JS

```
$(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-double-right').addClass('fa-angle-double-down');
$(this).siblings('dt').find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-double-down').addClass('fa-angle-double-right');
```

Comment: How can I able to close the first element? As in close all of the elements by default.

Comment: Like when the page first loads? Change `$('dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').addClass('hide');` to `$('dd').addClass('hide');` or just add the class to begin with in the html or set the `dd` to `display: none` in your css and not use a class at all.

Comment: Something is wrong on your first solutiion. Why is the first element has the right arrow icon though the accordion content is open? See this: http://prnt.sc/avj89f

Comment: On my second question or follow up question. Can you show me your fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3fpaa648/9/ adds the class 'active' to the first dt, thus fixing the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/3fpaa648/10/ shows how it would look with everything closed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method can be like that (similar to your method)

```
(function() {
    $('dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').addClass('hide');
    $('dl').on('click', 'dt', function() {

        $(this)
            .next()
                .slideDown(300)
                .siblings('dd')
                    .slideUp(300);

          $("dl").find("i").each(function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "fa fa-angle-double-down" );
            $(this).addClass("fa fa-angle-double-right");
          });
          $(this).find("i").addClass("fa fa-angle-double-down");

    });
})();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fpaa648/8/) example